# Flutter: Transferring items from one list into a different list

Tags: flutter

i have one `List` (growable) with an item (actually item 0:

```
items is of class Team

items[_id = 1, _team = "Team01", _note = "blabla"]
```

and I want to transfer it into another list with a different structure:

participants is of class `User`

```
participants[id = 1, name = "participant1"]
```

skipping the note and translating `_id` into id and so on.So at last the result would give me

```
participants[id = 1, name = "team01"]
```

(sorry for the writing, I describe it out of the debugger)

i tried something like this, but doesnt work with value:

```
List<TestTeam> participants;
for (var value in items) {
  participants.add(new TestTeam(value.id, value.team));
}
```

my class Team is defined like this:

```
class Team {
  int _id;
  String _team;
  String _note;

  Team(this._team, this._note);

  Team.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._id = obj['id'];
    this._team = obj['team'];
    this._note = obj['note'];
  }

  int get id => _id;
  String get team => _team;
  String get note => _note;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (_id != null) {
      map['id'] = _id;
    }
    map['team'] = _team;
    map['note'] = _note;

    return map;
  }

  Team.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map['id'];
    this._team = map['team'];
    this._note = map['note'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what you want by Drawing or other way

Comment: i want to transfer from one list to another, while both are type of different classes

Answer (score 0):

You should implement below way

```
void main() {
  List<Team> teams=[];
    List<User> participants=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    teams.add(Team(i,'Team_$i','Note_$i'));
  }
  for (var value in teams){
    participants.add(User(value.id,value.team));
  }
  
    for (var value in teams){
    print(value.toString());
  }
     for (var value in participants){
    print(value.toString());
  }

  

}

 class Team{
   int id;
   String team;
   String note; 
   
   Team(this.id,this.team,this.note);
   
   toString()=> 'Team Map :{id:$id,team:$team,note:$note}';
 }

class User{
   int id;
   String team;
    
   
   User(this.id,this.team);
   toString()=> 'User Map :{id:$id,team:$team}';
 }
```

Output

```
Team Map :{id:0,team:Team_0,note:Note_0}
Team Map :{id:1,team:Team_1,note:Note_1}
Team Map :{id:2,team:Team_2,note:Note_2}
Team Map :{id:3,team:Team_3,note:Note_3}
User Map :{id:0,team:Team_0}
User Map :{id:1,team:Team_1}
User Map :{id:2,team:Team_2}
User Map :{id:3,team:Team_3}
```

Comment: When i do this, then i got a fault on this line `participants.add(TestTeam(value.id, value.team));` Too many positional arguments, 0 expected

Comment: Where class of `TestTeam`